# .htaccess mod_rewrite for all files including specific string in the filename

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have huge number of files that unfortunately are not longer needed. But since some of them are already indexed by google, I would like to redirect traffic to another useful resource. (Using 301)

File's names are constructed as per example

xxxxxx-yyyyyy-zzzzzz-common-string.php

So the regex will have to redirect all files that have string "-common-string" in common and php extension.

I have no idea how to write RewriteCond and RewriteRule which would work in this case?
Can you help please. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just this single rule in your site root .htaccess should redirect all such URLs to your home page:

```
RedirectMatch 301 -common-string\.php$ /
```